# Inline display when using GalSim on iPython Notebook

Tags: galsim

It seems that all the demos write the image file to the system so that we can view it with DS9. Is there a way we can view the images we make inline on iPython Notebook, as we code? This would speed up my coding a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GalSim `Image` objects store the pixel values in a numpy array: `im.array`.  So if you're using an iPython notebook with `%matplotlib inline`, you can just do `plt.imshow(im.array)` to display an image of the data on the screen.